# C# - Login and Show the Name Of The Username and Disable the Button Depending on Login Title

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a login form(Window Form) where there's a column value of Staff and Business Manager. When the login is true, the page will redirect to other page where she/he can access the form. Inside the form, there's a button "View Masterlist."

When the user login is Staff, he/she can successfully proceed to form but the button is disable. Her/His name also appeared depending on the user account.

The same way with Business Manager, but the difference is the Business Manager can View the Masterlist.

On the Second page,

```
btn_masterlist.Enable = true;
```

Here's my Login Page

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from tbladmin where email='" + txt_username.Text + "' and password='" + txt_password.Text + "'", dt.connect);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows == true)
{
  dr.Read();
  Data.title = dr["title"].ToString();
  MessageBox.Show("You Have Successfully Signed In. Please Click \"OK\" to Continue...");
  Main menu = new Main();
  menu.Show();
  this.Hide();
 }
 else
 {
  MessageBox.Show(this, "Incorrect Username/Email or Password", "Sign Failed");
  return;
 }dr.Close();
```

Here's The Table Structure
[image]

Comment: Check if the user is a business manager after having stored this info during registeration! If title is manager btnmasterList.enabled=false if it is initialised as true

Comment: How can I check it sir?

Comment: @mark it depends on how your database table is structured, can you show  how your Db table looks like?

Comment: Sir, I added my table structure.

Comment: @mark To prevent SQL Injection Attacks in your application, it is strongly recommended to use parametrized commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create a property UserTitle in Main form

```
public string UserTitle { get; set; }
```

Then when creating Main form, pass it to main form

```
Data.title = dr["title"].ToString();
Main menu = new Main();
menu.UserTitle = Data.title;
menu.Show();
this.Hide();
```

2- In Main form Load event check if UserTitle is staff disable it, else enable it:

```
private void AdoSample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.UserTitle.ToLower=="staff")
        this.btn_masterlist.Enabled = false;
    else
        this.btn_masterlist.Enabled = true;
}
```

Please note it's strongly recommended to use parametrized query like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand("Select * from tbladmin where email = @email and password = @Password");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_username.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_password.Text);
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//Your Other Codes ...
```

Comment: Sir, How can I use it?

Comment: @mark you can simply use it instead of your equivalent codes.

Comment: Thank you sir! God bless! + :D

Answer (score 1):

During registeration store another field in database which should contain the employee type

```
 While(dr.read())
 {
     string EmployeeeType=dr["employeeType"].ToString();
     if(EmployeeType.Equals("manager"))
      frmMain.btnMasterList.Enabled=true;
     else
      frmMain.btnMasterList.Enabled=false;
 }
 frmMain.Show();
```

The while loop should only run once since there is only one row in DB that matches username and password

Don't forget to make the access specifier for button to public. FrmMain is an instance of the form containing btnMasterList! You can also use get;set;

Comment: Thank you sir! God bless and have a great day! + :D